# Find out video's resolution & duration

Tags: video

Any easy way to find out a video's resolution & duration?

I know one way is to parse the `ffprobe`'s output. But,

- I don't know how consistent the output is among different video files.
- and most importantly, I hope to avoid such parsing entirely.

I've tried

- `ffprobe -print_format json ...`
- `ffprobe -print_format compact ...`

But neither seems to be what they are supposed to be

> -print_format format  set the output printing format (available formats are: default, compact, csv, flat, ini, json, xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **MediaInfo**?
About:
https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo
//
Downloads:
https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download

But you need to **install** it.
On Windows (haven't tested on mac), it shows up as option on rightclick